# How to turn createStore in configureStore

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I need to transform createStore code in configureStore code

I've tried to turn this but unsuccessfully:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from './reducers/index'

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default DataProvider
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What wasn't successful? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, it's not anyone's job here to write the conversion for you. Please [edit] the post to share your attempt at implementing the redux store using modern redux as part of a complete [mcve]. See also: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore

Answer (score 1):

`configureStore` is part of the `@reduxjs/toolkit` package:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from './reducers/index'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [thunk],
    devTools: true
})

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default DataProvider
```

Comment: Thanks you very much everything work now